# PHP8.1 - how do I get imageavif() to work?

Tags: php, apache, avif, php-8.1

I recently upgraded my PHP version to 8.1-fpm and also upgraded Debian to Bullseye. I read somewhere that Bullseye comes with AVIF support but when I try to use `imageavif()`, I get the following error:

```
PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function imageavif()
```

I ran "php -i | grep AVIF" on my server and it returns:

```
ImageMagick supported formats => 3FR, 3G2, 3GP, AAI, AI, APNG, ART, ARW, AVI, AVIF, AVS, BGR, BGRA, BGRO, BIE, BMP, BMP2, BMP3, BRF, CAL, CALS, CANVAS, CAPTION, CIN, CIP, CLIP, CMYK, CMYKA, CR2, CR3, CRW, CUR, CUT, DATA, DCM, DCR, DCX, DDS, DFONT, DNG, DPX, DXT1, DXT5, EPDF, EPI, EPS, EPS2, EPS3, EPSF, EPSI, EPT, EPT2, EPT3, ERF, FAX, FILE, FITS, FRACTAL, FTP, FTS, G3, G4, GIF, GIF87, GRADIENT, GRAY, GRAYA, GROUP4, H, HALD, HDR, HEIC, HISTOGRAM, HRZ, HTM, HTML, HTTP, HTTPS, ICB, ICO, ICON, IIQ, INFO, INLINE, IPL, ISOBRL, ISOBRL6, J2C, J2K, JBG, JBIG, JNG, JNX, JP2, JPC, JPE, JPEG, JPG, JPM, JPS, JPT, JSON, K25, KDC, LABEL, M2V, M4V, MAC, MAGICK, MAP, MASK, MAT, MATTE, MEF, MIFF, MKV, MNG, MONO, MOV, MP4, MPC, MPG, MRW, MSL, MTV, MVG, NEF, NRW, NULL, ORF, OTB, OTF, PAL, PALM, PAM, PATTERN, PBM, PCD, PCDS, PCL, PCT, PCX, PDB, PDF, PDFA, PEF, PES, PFA, PFB, PFM, PGM, PGX, PICON, PICT, PIX, PJPEG, PLASMA, PNG, PNG00, PNG24, PNG32, PNG48, PNG64, PNG8, PNM, POCKETMOD, PPM, PREVIEW, PS, PS2, PS3, PSB, PSD, PTIF, PWP, RADIAL-GRADIENT, RAF, RAS, RAW, RGB, RGBA, RGBO, RGF, RLA, RLE, RMF, RW2, SCR, SCT, SFW, SGI, SHTML, SIX, SIXEL, SPARSE-COLOR, SR2, SRF, STEGANO, SUN, TEXT, TGA, THUMBNAIL, TIFF, TIFF64, TILE, TIM, TTC, TTF, TXT, UBRL, UBRL6, UIL, UYVY, VDA, VICAR, VID, VIDEO, VIFF, VIPS, VST, WBMP, WEBM, WEBP, WMV, WPG, X, X3F, XBM, XC, XCF, XPM, XPS, XV, XWD, YCbCr, YCbCrA, YUV
```

How do I get `imageavif()` to work? Am I missing something?

Edit: I ran the function "print_r(gd_info());" and this is the resulting array:

```
Array
(
    [GD Version] => 2.3.0
    [FreeType Support] => 1
    [FreeType Linkage] => with freetype
    [GIF Read Support] => 1
    [GIF Create Support] => 1
    [JPEG Support] => 1
    [PNG Support] => 1
    [WBMP Support] => 1
    [XPM Support] => 1
    [XBM Support] => 1
    [WebP Support] => 1
    [BMP Support] => 1
    [AVIF Support] => 
    [TGA Read Support] => 1
    [JIS-mapped Japanese Font Support] => 
)
```

Seems like I have GD but its AVIF support isn't set. How do I get it to support AVIFs?

Also, I am currently using `imagewebp()` and that function works just fine.

Edit: Thanks to [Nico Haase](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1116230/nico-haase) for pointing me to the GitHub issue for Ondřej Surý's PHP repository - https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1641

In the meantime, is there anything I can do to get `imageavif()` to work that wouldn't be too excessive or is it best to just wait?

Comment: `imageavif()` doesn't use ImageMagick/`Imagick`.  It uses GD.  You'll need to install `php-gd` (or something like that).

Comment: Looks like I have GD - updated question with more info.

Comment: Show us your PHP ini. and look yourself if the extension is enabled. (phpinfo() )

Comment: Does https://php.watch/versions/8.1/gd-avif help? Did you also install `libavif`? Also, how did you install PHP? Bullseye ships 7.4, it does not contain 8.1

Comment: Okay - so I tried `apt install libavif-dev` and I get the message `libavif-dev is already the newest version`. Do I need to do the `./configure` part as well? If so, that part is confusing and ambiguous. For example, `For production systems, make sure to enable other extensions as well.` - does that mean I need to explicitly enable webp even though it's already enabled and if I don't, it'll become disabled? I wish that step was written more clearly. Also, it doesn't explain the `./buildconf` command at all. Plus, the link to `How to compile PHP` goes to a massive confusing document.

Comment: You don't need to compile PHP on your own - but how did you install PHP in the first place? Bullseye does not ship 8.1

Comment: I just manually installed it.

Comment: What does that mean? Compiling from source? Using any other repository?

Comment: Oh, I use Ondřej Surý's repository at packages.sury.org/php

Comment: Then https://github.com/oerdnj/deb.sury.org/issues/1641 should help: there's an open bug report for the missing support

Comment: Ah, I see. Thanks! Guess I'll just wait until it's addressed then. Nothing I can do now, right?

Answer (score 2):

GD extension depends on the libavif package to provide the underlying AVIF codecs. GD extension requires libavif version 0.8.2 or higher.

**Ubuntu/Debian**

```
apt install libavif-dev
```

**RHEL/Fedora**

```
dnf install libavif-devel
```

Once the dependencies are installed, PHP can be compiled with AVIF support with the new --with-avif flag in the ./configure script.

```
./buildconf --force
./configure --enable-gd --with-avif
```

Note that the ./configure command above is just an example; For production systems, make sure to enable other extensions as well.

Source: https://php.watch/versions/8.1/gd-avif

Comment: `Package 'libavif-dev' has no installation candidate` Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to install Package 'libavif-dev' as there is no installation candidate on a ubuntu 20.04 server. So you can't recompile gdlib.

If you however use a ubuntu server 22.04 it works just fine.

The bug is described here

https://github.com/php/php-src/issues/12019

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libgd2/+bug/2031934#yui_3_10_3_1_1708785074264_150

Tested AVIF support with Ubuntu 20.04 and deb.sury.org repo PHP 8.3.3: AVIF image support has been disabled warning.
Tested AVIF support with Ubuntu 22.04 and deb.sury.org repo PHP 8.3.3: works.

AVIF support reported by your GD is a false positive. You're using Ubuntu 20.04, where system libgd doesn't support AVIF.