# how to enable "imageavif" in PHP8.1

Tags: php, php-8.1, avif

I using the the new php8.1 function is **imageavif** but that throw error message **undefined function** and then print the **gdinfo()** but avif is not enabled so how to enable it?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70398133/php8-1-how-do-i-get-imageavif-to-work

Answer (score 0):

You must compile PHP 8.1 GD extension (`--enable-gd`) with AVIF support (`--with-avif`) in the `./configure` script.

Source: https://php.watch/versions/8.1/gd-avif